# Hostname of machine changed unexpectedly to mongodb after reboot

Tags: linux, node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, hostname

I have mongodb 3.0.4 installed on my Ubuntu machine, and after I did a reboot I noticed that the hostname changed to `mongodb`.
Indeed I see `myuser@mongodb` instead of `myuser@myhostname` as it was before the reboot.
Again by running `cat /etc/hostname` I get `mongodb`.
And if I try to change it back again by running `sudo hostname myhostname` it shows this error `sudo: unable to resolve host mongodb`. This error shows up whenever I run `sudo [anything]`. I tried another reboot but this didn't fix the problem.

How to fix this? And why did this occur in the first place?
BTW the reboot was done after chaning default `ulimit` fildes number, which I did for node.js

Comment: Do you have an entry for `mongodb` in `/etc/hosts` perhaps?

Comment: @robertklep, there is no `mongodb` entry there, just `myhostname` and 2 `localhost`. Should there be a `mongodb` entry?

Comment: No, it might have caused such a name change if there was.

Comment: @robertklep, I just went to `/etc/hostname`, changed `mongodb` to `myhostname`, did a reboot and apparently this solved the issue. But why this happened in the first place is a mystery